# C - Generate random sequence with no repeats without shuffling

Tags: c, algorithm, random

I want to generate an array of the sequence `[0...1'000'000]` in random order **without shuffling**.

This means that I don't want to do:

```
int arr[1000000];

for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    arr[i] = i; 
}

shuffle(arr);
shuffle(arr);
```

I want to figure out how to do it without the "black-box" `shuffle` function. I also *don't want to randomly select an index* between `1` and `1'000'000` because at number `999'999` there would be only a `1/1'000'000` chance to continue.

I've been trying to think of a solution and I think the key is parallel arrays and looping backwards then using modulus to limit only to the indexes that you haven't already been to, but then I can't guarantee that the value I get is unique.

I don't want to use a HashSet or TreeSet implementation as well.

Comment: You want to generate a random permutation of 1M numbers. That's the problem definition, am I correct? Why do you think there is a solution within the constraints you define?

Comment: Yes. I want to fill an array of 1M size with values ranging from `1` to `1M` inclusive without any repeats and doing this all in good O complexity without using a shuffling algorithm.

Comment: Shuffling is *precisely* the way to do this.  What issue do you have with this technique?

Comment: @dbush I want to find an alternative way to do it simply to improve at algorithms.

Comment: You can have a *theoretical* algorithm, selecting an Godel-encoded permutation out of O(n!) permutations. But of course it is not feasible with n=1M.

Comment: By not feasible, do you mean you'd get to a situation where you'd have to randomly select an index and eventually it'd be too hard to guess the unoccupied index?

Comment: Is O(n^2) not acceptable?

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 Given n=1M? Hm. Doesn't look like improvement..

Comment: Sorry, by good O complexity I meant not guessing the index and having the program sit for ten minutes until it guesses the last one. What is `<sup>`?

Comment: A random selection of `1,...,n` w/o repeats is pretty much the definition of shuffle, any algorithm you'd come up with will be a shuffle if you like it or not.

Comment: Why are you calling your shuffle function twice in the statement of what you don't want to do?

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 Fisher-Yates/Knuth shuffle iterates through the array, and each successive location gets its finalized value based on a single swap with a randomized element from the remainder of the array.  Generating the random index to swap with and swapping are constant time ops, so the overall complexity is O(n), not O(n^2).

Comment: @pjs My comment was not about the currently accepted answer. It was a general question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in `O(n)` time with two lists, one with the number (initialy) in order, and one in the resulting order.

You start with `n` elements in order in your source list.  Then you select a random number mod `n`.  That gives you the next element, which you place in the destination list.

Now the key part.  If you were to pick a random number between `0` and `n-1` each time, as you seem to think a shuffle does, you have an increasing chance of selecting a number you selected before.  So how do you handle this?  By *decreasing* the available list of number to select from.

In the source list, after selecting a number, you move the last element of the list to the index that was just used.  You now have a list of `n-1` numbers to chose from.  So on the next iteration you take a random number mod `n-1`.  Keep going until your source list only has one element.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define LEN 10

int main()
{
    int a[LEN], b[LEN];
    int i, val;
    int count = LEN;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i=0;i<LEN;i++) {
        a[i]=i+1;
    }
    for (i=0;i<LEN;i++) {
        val = rand() % count;
        b[i] = a[val];
        a[val] = a[count-1];
        count--;
    }
    for (i=0;i<LEN;i++) {
        printf("%d ", b[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

Here's a slightly more efficient version that doesn't use two arrays and is therefore `O(1)` space:

```
int a[LEN];
int i, val, tmp;

srand(time(NULL));

for (i=0;i<LEN;i++) {
    a[i]=i+1;
}
for (i=0;i<LEN-1;i++) {
    val = (rand() % (LEN - 1 - i)) + i + 1;
    tmp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[val];
    a[val] = tmp;
}
for (i=0;i<LEN;i++) {
    printf("%d ", a[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

Comment: The code violate the restriction `without shuffling.` (and thus does not answer the question). (your second for loop is pretty much [fisher yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle))

Comment: @amit I think he meant we are not allow to use a black-box shuffle function.

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 I see nothing in question nor comments to support that assumption.

Comment: @amit Well, you are right. I guessed it, because otherwise it doesn't make any sense

Comment: Anyway, this is the best algorithm one can get. But it should be mentioned that it's O(n) time *and* space complexity

Comment: Isn't it possible for `val` to be the same integer twice in a row, thus overwritting an older value?

Comment: @Hatefiend It's exactly the point. The "old" `a[val]` is already in your  `b`.

Comment: @Hatefiend It could, however the value that was there the last time that index was selected was replaced with the value that was at the end of the list.  So you're not reusing values.

Comment: Correction to my first comment: This is not an implementaiton of fisher yates (which is more efficient), it's something else, though still a shuffle nontheless.

Comment: And to be exact, this solution is basically shuffling an aux array b, and copying it to a. (Edit version is straight shuffle, seems like FY variant...)

Comment: Thanks, I see how this works now. This was exactly what I was looking for. I wanted to randomly place elements as I was adding them to the array, not add `1` through `n` to the array then shuffle.

Comment: The second one is precisely F-Y (or one of its variants); the first one is essentially equivalent but requires twice as much space. Since both start by initializing an array to the sequence of integers in order, I fail to see any reason to consider the first one better. But beauty lies in the eye of the beholder.

Answer (score 1):

The O(N) answer is great but here is an alternative way using binary search and [binary indexed tree](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/binary-indexed-trees/) to do this in O(NlogN).

```
arr = []
N = 1000,000
for i from 0 to N-1
     low = 0
     high = N-1
     mid = (low+high)/2
     while low < high
         if full(low,mid)
             low = mid+1
         else if full(mid+1,high)
             high = mid
         else
             if rand() < 0.5
                  low = mid+1
             else
                  high = mid
     mark(low) // marking the element in binary indexed tree
     arr[i] = low
```

The function `full` is implemented using binary indexed tree and checks whether all the elements in the range given are marked or not.
Both `mark` and `full` have O(logN) complexity.

Comment: You seem to be randomly selecting half of the space based on the size of the range rather than the occupancy of the range. That will cause a small bias to creep into the result. If you chose which half to use by comparing the random number to the ratio of available values on the left to total available, the algorithm would work, but it is still unnecessarily complicated. (You can use a binary index tree to maintain availability counts in O(log N), so doing it right doesn't cost extra.)

Comment: The OP stated he doesn't want to use trees.